# How to use LLVM library in c++ Xcode project?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, include, llvm

I'm loosely following the [tutorial to implement Kaleidoscope on the LLVM website](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/index.html), and I'm at the point where I need to actually use the LLVM library for code generation. I've installed LLVM 13 using homebrew (`brew install llvm`), but I can't figure out how to use it in a c++ project in Xcode. I just get the error `'llvm/whatever/whatever' file not found` for every file I try to include:

```
#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Constants.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Type.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Verifier.h"
```

I've tried adding the include folder (`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.1_1/include` for me) to the header search paths in Xcode, which seems to do something but I end up with the error `Undefined symbol: llvm::DisableABIBreakingChecks`, and hundreds of different warnings.

All I want is to be able to use LLVM code generation in a small c++ project. Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also doing that tutorial. I'll tell you how I got it to work, but since I'm not an LLVM expert, I don't know if this is the best way.

I checked out and built LLVM from source, as [described here](https://www.llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-the-source-code-and-building-llvm). Installing with brew like you did should also work fine.

Next, I looked at the build command they give in the tutorial:

```
clang++ -g -O3 toy.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core` 
        -o toy
```

I can run that `llvm-config` command from my build directory and it gives me the flags that I need to somehow give to Xcode.

```
> bin/llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core 

-I/Users/rob/Foo/llvm-project/llvm/include 
-I/Users/rob/Foo/llvm-project/build/include 
-std=c++14 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti 
-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS

-L/Users/rob/Foo/llvm-project/build/lib 
-Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names

-lLLVMCore -lLLVMRemarks -lLLVMBitstreamReader 
-lLLVMBinaryFormat -lLLVMSupport -lLLVMDemangle

-lm -lz -lcurses -lxml2
```

I put those `-I` paths in the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting, and the `-L` path in `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS`. In Xcode those values are a list of paths, so you add the paths without the `-I` or `-L` part. I then put the `-l` library arguments in `OTHER_LDFLAGS`, and the `-D` arguments in `OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS`.

After that, it compiled and ran from Xcode. I did not yet translate all of the output from `llvm-config` into Xcode build settings. For example, I did nothing about these:

```
-std=c++14 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti
-Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names
```

Remains to be seen if that will cause problems later.